# glassfish hangs on hibernate Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory

Tags: spring, hibernate, glassfish

I am working on android project with the following technologies : glassfish, hibernate, spring, REST services and android sdk. My problem is that after a few executed services from the android app with the rest services, the service is just loading and nothing happen. When I look on the Glassfish log, there is not an error. The log stays on Using `ASTQueryTranslatorFactory` and thats all. To make the things work I need to restart the server. It is strange because that happens after 5 or 6 transactions with the database. Can someone help me with that issue?

Thats on the log after the glassfish/spring/hibernate freezes

```
    [2015-06-03T16:52:08.211+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] [tid: _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1433339528211] [levelValue: 800] [[
      HHH000043: Configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml]]
    [2015-06-03T16:52:08.211+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] [tid: _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1433339528211] [levelValue: 800] [[
      HHH000040: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml]]
    [2015-06-03T16:52:08.221+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration] [tid: _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1433339528221] [levelValue: 800] [[
      HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null]]
    [2015-06-03T16:52:08.271+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect] [tid: _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1433339528271] [levelValue: 800] [[
      HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect]]
    [2015-06-03T16:52:08.311+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionFactoryInitiator] [tid: _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1433339528311] [levelValue: 800] [[
      HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)]]
    [2015-06-03T16:52:10.205+0300] [glassfish 4.0] [INFO] [] [org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory] [tid: _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=http-listener-1(2)] [timeMillis: 1433339530205] [levelValue: 800] [[
      HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory]]
```

Comment: Why is the application context being loaded? That shouldn't happen as you should only load it once, you aren't doing things like `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` just to get beans do you?

Comment: I every class where I have REST service I am doing :
private ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml")  in the constructor, is that wrong ?

Comment: Yes that is wrong, so wrong... Never create an application context just because you need one. What you are doing each time you are basically recreating your whole application, you want a single instance. The `ContextLoaderListener` should be the one loading the configuration, for your rest services (assuming they are spring based) use `@Autowired` to get the dependencies, don't do `context.getBean`. If you start loading your application all the time you will run into issues like you have now.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will try that! I am beginner in spring and obviously is my stupid mistake...

Comment: Deinum,  thank you for your help. Now I am using ContextLoaderListener with @Autowired annotation and it is pretty better. But the issue stays... I have made some changes on the Glassfish server. I maed the heap size to 2GB and it is much better but again the server stops. I think the garbage collector is the the problem. Can you give me some advice? I was change the code above with the new setting which you recommended. Thanks!